# List<object>: how to apply a "where" for some index element?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, object

I've this kind of List of object:

```
.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new List<object>()
{
    p.ID,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : null,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.Month.ToString() : null,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.Year.ToString() : null,
    p.Clinic.ID,
    p.Clinic.Name,
    p.Patient.LastName + " " + p.Patient.FirstName,
    p.Patient.Gold,
    p.Patient.PromoSmiles,
    p.TreatmentType.Description ?? "",
    p.PaymentMethod.Description ?? "",
    p.ActivityPayments.Select((q, index) => new
    {
        Description = q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.ACCONTO ? labelAcconto : q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.SINGOLOPAGAMENTO && p.PaymentMethod.ID == 1 ? labelRata + (index - p.ActivityPaymentsNonSinglePaymentCount + 1) : labelImporto,
        Amount = q.Amount,
        Date = q.Date,
        Paid = q.Paid
    })
}).ToList();
```

The last item (i.e. data[11]) is a list of objects.

I want to apply a Where before the .ToList(), so that it filters only objects of data where data[11] list have at least one Paid = true.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your Select return a List<object> where any property of the source is now an element in the List(if that initializer even compiles) and then you call ToList on that so you get a List<List<object>>. Thats sounds very unhelpful. Typos or actually intended?

Comment: a list containing different things is likely to produce errors. Simply don't store diferent things into a single collection. Either is your list a list of items, or a list of lists, but not both.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I know. But old code, can't do a huge refactoring. Must live with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Cast `data[11]` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

```
.Where(data => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)data[11])
                .Any(q => q.Paid))
```

2. Apply `Where` before `Select`

```
.AsEnumerable()
.Where(p => p.ActivityPayments.Any(q => q.Paid))
.Select(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an anonymous object instead of a list of objects in the first `Select` method.

```
var data = .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new
{
    p.ID,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : null,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.Month.ToString() : null,
    p.DateActivity.HasValue ? p.DateActivity.Value.Year.ToString() : null,
    p.Clinic.ID,
    p.Clinic.Name,
    p.Patient.LastName + " " + p.Patient.FirstName,
    p.Patient.Gold,
    p.Patient.PromoSmiles,
    p.TreatmentType.Description ?? "",
    p.PaymentMethod.Description ?? "",
    p.ActivityPayments.Select((q, index) => new
    {
        Description = q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.ACCONTO ? labelAcconto : q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.SINGOLOPAGAMENTO && p.PaymentMethod.ID == 1 ? labelRata + (index - p.ActivityPaymentsNonSinglePaymentCount + 1) : labelImporto,
        Amount = q.Amount,
        Date = q.Date,
        Paid = q.Paid
    })
}).ToList();

var filteredData = data.where(x => x.ActivityPayments.Paid).ToList();
```