# Cannot cast object type to representative class with same properties

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have an `ExpandoObject` (`recordValue` in this example) that I traverse through and I need to extract the value for given key. For that purpose, I do the following:

```
var objectValue = recordValue.Where(x => x.Key == objId).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns me a type `object` and if I check the value of the object in a debug mode, I get the following data:

```
Count=2:
[0] = "random string" (of type string)
[1] = Count = 3 {(1, 2, 3)} (of type List<long>)
```

I made a class named `Info` that has two properties, the first one string and the second one list:

```
public class Info
{
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public List<long> List { get; set; }
}
```

C# says that the type is `object` so I tried to cast via `(Info) objectValue` but then I get an error that ``` Generic.List``1(System.Object) cannot be casted into Info ```. I tried to cast it into a `List<Info>` but still no luck. Since it says that it's a `List<System.Object>`, I tried to iterate it but this time I got an error that `object` has no method `Count`. I tried to get the values by passing index to `objectValue` but still getting an error that indexing is not allowed on type `object`.

This got me so confused and I don't know whether my variable is `object` or `List<System.Object>` and I cannot find a way to cast the value into my class `Info`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I cast this `object` into my `Info`? If not possible, at least how can I extract the string and the list from `objectValue`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just a single line of code and the `Info` declaration. But fundamentally you shouldn't expect to be able to cast something as an `Info` if it's not *actually* an `Info` at execution time.

Comment: Are you the author of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360569/listobject-how-to-apply-a-where-for-some-index-element/)?

Comment: No @shingo. I'll try to include a reproducible example asap #Jon Skeet